# Why isn't my event bubbling

Tags: javascript

Here's some demo code：

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="child">
        click
    </div>
</div>
<script>
   document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
       if(e.target.classList.contains('child')){
           console.log('child')
       }
       if(e.target.id==='test'){
           console.log('test')
       }
       if(e.target.tagName === 'HTML'){
           console.log('html')
       }
   }, false)
</script>
```

When I click text, the console only logs 'child'. Why doesn't the click event bubble up to the parentNode #test? Even the html element can't get the click event.

Can anyone explain what the problem is?

Comment: You dont understand what it is "event capturing" and "event bubbling". Learn about it more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The event is bubbling that is why the handle registered to the document object is getting fired. The document object is the top most object in the dom, ie it is the parent of the html element. If the bubbling was not happening then the handler would not have got called.

But in all the handlers [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) will refer to the original element from where the event started that is why it is always referring to the child element

> A reference to the object that dispatched the event. It is different
>   than [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) when the event handler is called during the
>   bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

If you want to test the ancestor element, then you need to traverse up from the event target and see whether any of those satisfies the condition

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  while (target) {
    if (target.classList.contains('child')) {
      snippet.log('child')
    }
    if (target.id === 'test') {
      snippet.log('test')
    }
    if (target.tagName === 'HTML') {
      snippet.log('html')
    }
    target = target.parentNode;
  }
}, false)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<div id="test">
  <div class="child">
    click
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also note that `event.target.parentNode` would return the parentNode and you can go over that tree until document if you want. Or use the `event.path` of nodes in the `target` tree

Comment: @ArunPJohnny I just see it. Only two seconds between my comment and your edit. Sorry about that!

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I can understand it. You are so nice!

Comment: It's good to use snippet.js to debug in mobile web. But the snippet may have a mistake   "else if (typeof object === "object")", your arg[0] is msg, so this would be "else if (typeof msg === "object")".